# I want to pass an image to my ImageView in another activity?

Tags: java, android

I have a gridView and in my activity class I set the images in my drawable into my gridView layout. so when an image is pressed/clicked a toast message says the number of the image so if i have 10 images and you click the third image the toast mesaage just says 3.

```
 gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(Second.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

how can I instead replace the Toast line of code and  use code that will send that picture that was clicked to another activity's image View.

Comment: You can pass information from one activity to another by using a bundle. This bundle can be set on the intent object and can be retrieved by using getIntent.getExtras()

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- Base64 encode the bitmap itself and put it in the intent as a String
- Send a reference (like the image hash, image path) to the second activity

If fetching the image is a cheap operation, then the later option probably is better.